# How to pass an indefinite amount of arguments to a console.log call?

Tags: javascript, function

This is semi-related to passing an indefinite amount of arguments to a function:

```
myFunc = function () {
  // process 'arguments' variable
};

myFunc.apply(null, ['string1', 'string2']);
```

Except `console.log` is a tricky one, because if you pass it an array of strings, it will literally print the array to the console. What I'm shooting for is something like this:

```
myConsoleLog = function () {
  console.log(arguments);
};

myConsoleLog.apply(null, ['My name is %s.', 'Franco']);
```

Expected result shown in the web console:

> My name is Franco.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log(arguments)` should be `console.log.apply(console, arguments)`

```js
myConsoleLog = function () {
  console.log.apply(console, arguments);
};

myConsoleLog.apply(null, ['My name is %s.', 'Franco']);
```

### Spread operator

> The spread operator allows an expression to be expanded in places where multiple arguments (for function calls) or multiple elements (for array literals) are expected.

ECMAScript ES6 added a new operator that lets you do this in a more practical way: **...[Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Examples)**. Example without using the `apply` method:

```js
myConsoleLog = function () {
  console.log(...arguments);
};

myConsoleLog(...['My name is %s.', 'Franco']);
```

<kbd>Note</kbd> This snippet returns a syntax error if your browser still uses ES5.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `apply` in you custom function:

```
console.log.apply(console, arguments)
```

Then you can call it like:

```
myConsoleLog('My name is %s', 'Franco')
// or
myConsoleLog.apply(null, ['My name is %s', 'Franco'])
```